# Is there a way to download file from a directory in SFTP server as soon as it is created/copied (to it) through SFTP Client

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

I am using paramiko multithreaded SFTP server and paramiko client to establish a SFTP session, In my project I maintain two folders each on server and client respectively as soon as a new file is created or copied to the concerned folder in SFTP server I need to download it to the SFTP client folder,Is it possible in paramiko. Remember I may or may not delete the file from SFTP server once it is downloaded by all clients.

Comment: I'm sorry if this comment will sound crass; Is it possible? Yes, most probably. Will we write the code for you? Most improbable. Please show us your current progress, and we'll help you if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mr.Hampus Larsson, I have successfully created server and client and was able to upload and download files as i wish, but I just need people like you to guide me to the right direction for solving my problem!

Comment: As @Hampus correctly stated, your question is way too broad. What is your immediate problem? Detecting the changes? Downloading the files?

Comment: Hello Mr.Martin Prikryl, Let me make it clear, I will have a folder in the server machine whenever a file pops inside the folder , that must be downloaded by the client - Regards Mr.B

Comment: We know that. What we do not know, is what *problem* you have with implementing that.

Comment: Sorry Mr.Martin Prikryl for delayed response I found another thread of yours where I can download last modified file which I think would solve my problem instead of relying on some event in program to trigger client to download file once it is created. Thanks Martin and Hampus I will work on this solution and let you know guys, Thanks